# How to get multiple labels' values via class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How could I get all values of labels that contains class "timeAuction"?

I am writing JavaScript function that will get each label with class name `timeAuction` and modify its value. I've got random number of labels with this class name.

Here's my code that renders html:

```
<label id="@Html.Raw("time" + item.IDAuc)" class="displayLabelProduct timeAuction">
    @diff.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss")
</label>
```

I would need to go through each label with this class, something like for loop and modify it.

Comment: With jQuery, `$('.timeAuction').text(function(){//anything})`

Comment: See [SO Documentation for DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dom/2658/retrieving-elements/8852/by-class-name#t=201609022014123132209) for an example without jQuery, and the [SO Documentation for jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/389/selectors/2115/types-of-selectors#t=20160902201510344004) for an example using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all elements using the class selector:

```
var allElements = $(".timeAuction");
```

You can also use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate the collection.

```
$(".timeAuction").each(function() {
   $(this).text("Random value");
});
```

**Full snippet showing modification of labels:**

```js
$(".timeAuction").each(function(counter) {
   $(this).text("New Label " + counter);
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="displayLabelProduct timeAuction">
    Label 1
</label>

<label class="displayLabelProduct timeAuction">
    Label 2
</label>

<label class="displayLabelProduct timeAuction">
    Label 3
</label>

<label class="displayLabelProduct timeAuction">
    Label 4
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with javascript then, this is how it gonna work:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("timeAuction");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  // modify as you want
}
```